# I've made a number of local changes, which I'd like to git-commit to a new branch on the shared server - how do I do that?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I've checked out code from a shared repository, and done some work on it. Along the way, I've been merging changes from the shared repository into my code.

I would like to push my local repo to a new branch on the shared repository, so others may access them, while at the same time not damaging the shared repo.

How would I do this using Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create and push a new feature branch, you can:

1. `git branch BRANCH_NAME`
2. `git checkout BRANCH_NAME`
3. `git commit` as needed
4. `git push origin BRANCH_NAME:BRANCH_NAME`

The last command pushes the branch to your shared repository (I assume that is `origin` for you).

"[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)" is a good tutorial.

The [Git Book](http://progit.org/book/ch3-2.html) also has a lot of good information.